# Play Framework - How to Query a Model using 'IN'?

Tags: java, playframework

How can I get the same results in Play Framework's Model Queries?

```
SELECT * FROM MyModel WHERE status IN (1, 5, 8) ORDER BY createdAt;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried

```
MyModel.find("status IN (:ids) ORDER BY createdAt").bind("ids", idExs).fetch();
```

Answer (score 1):

If `(1, 5, 8)` is a constant, it's pretty straightforward:

```
List<MyModel> r = MyModel.find("status in (1, 5, 8) order by createdAt").fetch();
```

If it should be a parameter:

```
List<Integer> s = Arrays.asList(1, 5, 8);
List<MyModel> r = MyModel.find("status in :s order by createdAt")
    .bind("s", s).fetch();
```

An important point here is that you can use `in` clause with named parameters only, not with positional (`?`) ones, due to limitation of Hibernate.