# Play Framework query with IN condition

Tags: playframework, conditional-statements

How to perform a query in Play! Framework with IN condition? I've followed the solution from this link [Play Framework - How to Query a Model using 'IN'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446251/play-framework-how-to-query-a-model-using-in), but I get an Illegal Arugment Exception error:

```
IllegalArgumentException occured : org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: cannot define positional parameter after any named parameters have been defined [from models.Post where (category_id in (:cat)) AND (gender like ?) AND (name like ? OR description like ?) AND isComplete is ? order by created_date desc]
```

and this is my code..

```
        String arrString[] = category.split(",");
        List<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<arrString.length; i++) {
            listString.add(arrString[i]);
        }

        posts = Post.find(                  
            "(category_id in (: cat)) AND (gender like? ) AND (name like? OR description like? ) AND isComplete is? " +
            "order by created_date desc", gender, search, search, true
        ).bind("cat", listString).from(0).fetch(50);
```

Can't I simply use the (? ) syntax for IN. so it will be something like:

```
        posts = Post.find(                  
            "(category_id in (? )) AND (gender like? ) AND (name like? OR description like? ) AND isComplete is? " +
            "order by created_date desc", category, gender, search, search, true
        ).from(0).fetch(50);
```

Where did I do wrong? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With something like

```
import play.db.helper.SqlQuery;
...
Set<String> categories = ...;
posts = Post.find("(category_id in "+SqlQuery.inlineParam(categories)+" AND ...")....fetch();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work, try following:

```
posts = Post.find("category_id in (?)", ids).from(0).fetch(50);
```

Following code works for me with EntityManager:

```
JPA.em().createNativeQuery("select from posts where category_id in (:ids)").setParameter("ids", ids).getResultList();
```

Where "`ids`" is "`List<Integer> ids`"